# Returning An Integer From A List Of Fractional Numbers

Tags: excel-formula

I have searched relentlessly and, incredibly, have not been able to solve what seems to be an almost childish formula dilemma. To keep it simple:

A column of numbers all having fractional values, example:

```
    D
1   13.8
2   3.3
3   24.1
4   13.2
5   16.1
6   28.1
7   16.2
```

The list can be phrased either as D1:D7 or as a defined table.

I want to return a true statement if the integer: 13, only (no fractional values), is found in this list. Of course, it can be seen to appear twice, but once is enough to do the job.

I've tried applying TRUNC and INT functions to various convolutions of MATCH and INDEX functions, but no success.

Comment: How about `=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(13,D1:D7,0)))` ?

Comment: It's a good idea to also tag questions like this with the specific version you're using, such as `excel-2007`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following formula:

```
=and(countifs(a:a, ">=13", a:a, "<14"))
'for non-countifs versions
=sumproduct((d1:d7>=13)*(d1:d7<14))
```

While AND is typically used to combine boolean operations, here it is used to convert any non-zero count to TRUE and a zero count to FALSE.

[image]

You can see how this plays out for *individual* items in the following graphic, where each `b` cell only looks at its equivalent `a` cell:

[image]

Comment: See image added above.

Comment: @Destiny, suggest you post the error message along with what you actually typed in.

Comment: Yes; I put that in exactly as indicated and receive the #NAME? error.

Comment: @Destiny, works fine for me. Can you tell us which version of Excel you're using and cut'n'paste the formula into a comment box (*not* retype, there's too much scope for typos in that method).

Comment: Found the problem: my older version doesn't support countifs. Any alternate suggestions?

Comment: We used to use sumproduct when there was no countifs but you don't want to use full column references. e.g. `=sumproduct((d1:d7>=13)*(d1:d7<14))`.

Comment: btw, the *de facto* standard used in [tag:excel] is [tag:excel-2010]. If features are used in a version above that the version restriction is mentioned. Similarly, if you are asking a question about a version below that, you should mention the version.

Comment: Perfect! I want to use a named table, anyway. So, this is fine. Many thanks! I'll remember to mention the version in the future.

Comment: @paxdiablo - thanks for the assist. I think it's resolved now.

Comment: @Jeeped: the ***de-jure*** standard is as per the tag info: Questions tagged with excel should be version-agnostic. In any case, you've covered the earlier versions as well now. I wonder if it will work on my old copy of Excel 2.0 under Win 3.1 :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo - that may be the written rule but it is generally acknowledged that 2010 is the standard. I used to annotate when using AGGREGATE but I don't anymore; only for features in xl2013 or xl2016.Office 365. In any event, pre-xl2007 versions should be mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following array formula. Once you type it and you want to enter it, you have to do Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

=OR (INT(D1:D7)=13)

If you are doing negative numbers, you should change INT for TRUNC.

[image]